# Place child of scrollable div center-view

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scrollable div somewhere on-screen.

I have a child of that div somewhere in it.

How can I scroll the div to place this child in the center of the visible region?

(How would I determine the visible width and height of the div, and how would I scroll to place a rectangular control centered in this?)

Comment: You need to do that using pure JS or you user some libraries, jQuery for example?

Comment: I would much-prefer to have pure JS.  Explaining how to do it with jQuery may of course be useful to other readers and I'd upvote that too ;)

Answer (score 0):

`element.scrollIntoView()` might be what your looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/a9s2G/

[scrollIntoView docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

Comment: You could do it by using `scrollintoview()` on an element matching the size of the scroll area and having the content in that element centered.

Comment: How would you determine the size of the visible area though?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can try [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin.

In pure js this can be done using [element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop). You will need to get position of your element inside `<div>` and than using that value scroll main div.

To calculate inner element position you will need to get it offset top and left property related to the parent element using [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop) and [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft) properties.

To center your element you may also need to use [element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft)

Comment: how do you compute the offsets to send to `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` ?

Comment: Surely you need to know the visible size of the div too?  I've worked out how to get its content size, but not its in-window size